# Indexing on a field produces a warning

Tags: hibernate, lucene

An application log is filled with following warnings:

```
o.h.s.u.i.InternalAnalyzerUtils.analyzeSortableValue HSEARCH000321: The analysis of field 'ipDisplay' produced multiple tokens. Tokenization or term generation (synonyms) should not be used on sortable fields. Only the first token will be indexed.
```

This is an annotation which produces a warning in logs:

```
@SortableField(forField = INDEX_FIELD_IP_DISPLAY_SORT)
    @Fields({
            @Field(name = INDEX_FIELD_IP_DISPLAY, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = LowerCaseAnalyzer.class)),
            @Field(name = INDEX_FIELD_IP_DISPLAY_SORT, analyze = Analyze.NO, index = Index.NO, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = LowerCaseBridge.class))
    })
```

I guess there is some issue with performance as mentioned in , but I still can not pinpoint it. I couldn't find an explanation in google, how this warning is produced by a code and how can I make it disappear without compromising indices and search? Only reference I've found is this: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/sorting-bridge-causes-mass-indexer-speed-degradation/2952 but I'm not sure if it's the same case.